# How do I retrieve a form collection's prototype attribute from within a controller (Symfony2)?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.2

I'm having trouble getting a form collection's prototype attribute within a controller for inclusion in a JSON response, the furthest I have got (i.e. no errors are being thrown) is with the following, however the returned value is empty.

```php
$form      = $this->createForm(new MyType());
$prototype = $form->get('myCollection')->getConfig()->getAttribute('prototype');
```

I've also tried creating the form's view, and pulling the attribute from there, however the `prototype` key is not defined here...

```php
$form      = $this->createForm(new MyType());
$view      = $form->createView();
$prototype = $view->children['myCollection']->vars['attr']['prototype'];
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

(Symfony 2.2.4)

Comment: Do you have allow_add = true when the collection is added? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned: The form is actually used on a page and is working fine. I have a second form for adding further options to a select within the first form's collection, via AJAX. I'm wanting to update the collection's prototype so that the newly added options are available when additional items are added.

Comment: Okay.  I have not tried that.  But instead of trying to change the prototype in your controller, consider passing the necessary information to your form type and have it add the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I can get what I'm after by rendering just the prototype attribute of my form's collection field, this feels like the long way around, but it works.

```
// Controller method
$form      = $this->createForm(new MyType());
$view      = $form->createView()->children['myCollection'];
$prototype = $this->renderView('MyBundle:Foo:prototype.html.twig', array('form' => $view));
```

```
<!-- Template (MyBundle:Foo:prototype.html.twig) -->
{{ form_widget(form.vars.prototype) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$prototype = $view->children['myCollection']->vars['prototype'];`

Comment: This appears to hold a further `FormView` object, which then has a `children` property containing the individual field elements, it also has its own `vars` property, but no generated HTML in there. I'm wondering if the prototype string is generated somewhere in the view renderer, I just can't find it...

Comment: Correct, you would then need to take this `FormView` block and render it using a `FormRenderer` that implements the `Symfony\Component\Form\FormRendererInterface`